# What is wrong with my AndroidManifest.xml? Syntax error?

Tags: android, xml, manifest

Here it is.. I'm getting **Parser exception for C:\Users\your name here\sandorfalot\WobblyPsyche\AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.**

This is a syntax error, right?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.WobblyPsyche"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >
   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/WobblyPsyche"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.WobblyPsyche"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/WobblyPsyche"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the beginning

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and changing your activity name line to this

```
android:name="com.example.WobblyPsyche.MainActivity"
```

Comment: any activity with the a name prefixed with a "." automatically has the package name stuck on the front, so ".MainActivity" is valid syntax

Comment: there is no need give absolute class path